# Bluemix CLI Joomla 3.8 installation final steps

Tags: joomla, cloud, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, cleardb

I am installing Joomla 3.8 for a demo purpose on Bluemix, through Cloud Foundy - cf push,

And the URL is : https://joomlacloud.eu-gb.mybluemix.net/installation/index.php#

as i use ClearDb as external database, the new security tool since joomla 3.7.4 requests a file created in the /install folder to be removed.

Message : "Afin de confirmer que vous êtes le propriétaire de ce site Web, supprimez le fichier "_JoomlaUQEvA8900RHAnVyBbf1Zs.txt" que nous venons de créer dans le dossier "installation" de votre site Joomla."

Does someone explain me how i can do access to this file for removing ?

Thank you in advance
Yves

Comment: Using machine translation, here's what the message in French seems to say in English: "To confirm that you are the owner of the Web site, delete the file "_JoomlaUQEvA8900RHAnVyBbf1Zs.txt" that we have just created in the "Installing" your Joomla site."

Comment: Thank you Bill, and my question is how to access bluemix space to remove this file, because i can't finish the joomla installation without this removal. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run `cf ssh <your-app-name>`.  Then `cd app/`.  You'll now be in the root of your application.  From there locate the file and `rm` it.  The change will be instant.

Things will be more confusing if you have multiple instances of your application.  In that case, you might need to `cf ssh` into all of them to find where the file was written, or just scale down to one while you're installing.

Just keep in mind that any files you `cf push`'d with your application will return when your application is restarted, intentionally or otherwise.  If you need to remove a file that you `cf push`'d then you should do so locally and `cf push` a second time without that file or files.

Hope that helps!